# how to setup firebase project in flutter without Firebase CLI

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I setup firebase project in flutter without Firebase CLI. I am doing this because I wanted to use FCM only but firebase CLI doesn't allow only to use FCM.
If u have any work-around for this please let know.

Code so that I can start working on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for this one by myself.
For right now there no direct way to acheive this thing. But there is work-around for this.
Add Firebase core and FCM library in yaml file

```
  firebase_core: ^2.14.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.4
```

Now add following code in build.gradle at app level file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this code at build.gradle at project level file

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

Thank you.